# OSX Server Login issue, ssh works, console does not

Tags: mac-osx, mac, login, osx-leopard

We have a brand new OSX Snow Leopard, we created some user accounts, the accounts can login from ssh, but not from the GUI Login prompt. The login used to create these also does not work after we gave Login Window privilege to the originally affected users in an attempt to fix this.

Secure.log file has no errors, says "Login Window Showing progress"

system.log shows that jabberd keeps trying to connect to router @ 127.0.0.1 and fails

It appears that we may have accidentally disabled login window privileges to all local users. Don't know how to restore this from command like, we do have admin privileges.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can log in with Server Admin from another Macintosh, you should be able to see and modify all of the primary configuration parameters with the GUI from there.   If you can't do that due to firewall configuration, you can temporarily disable the firewall by logging in over SSH and doing:
   sudo serveradmin stop ipfilter

Once you've done that, I'd first check the Server Admin and visit the Access tab once you've logged in.   This is one of the primary all-or-nothing controls for windowed login to the server box.   Look at the Services sub-tab and see what Login Window is configured for.   This should either be enabled for all users and groups, or for some group or selection of users that is appropriate for your location.   If you think the group should be working, but it isn't, you'll need to fire up Workgroup Manager to access the servers user and group database.